# Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT>

Tags: html

I have this problem, y really don´t understand how can i fix it. Please i need help with this.

The label's for attribute doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly.
To fix this issue, make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field.

This is my code

```
<label for="billing_country" class="">País / Región&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obligatorio">*</abbr></label>
```

Please i need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) claims to be associated with a particular form element, but that form element doesn't exist.

If this label is associated with a form element, that element needs to exist.  For example, it can be outside the label:

```
<label for="billing_country">País / Región&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obligatorio">*</abbr></label>
<input type="text" id="billing_country" name="billing_country">
```

Or nested within the label, in which case the `for` attribute isn't needed:

```
<label>
  País / Región&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obligatorio">*</abbr>
  <input type="text" name="billing_country">
</label>
```

Alternatively, if that label *isn't* associated with a form element, change it to something else.  A `<span>`, for example:

```
<span>País / Región&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obligatorio">*</abbr></span>
```

Or any other simple text element, or no wrapping element at all if you don't need one:

```
País / Región&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="obligatorio">*</abbr>
```